# JQuery mouse event occurring many times, want it only once

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a JQuery slider and I've hit a roadblock. I'm new to both Javascript and JQuery however. Here is my code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Experimentation</title>
    <style type="text/css">

#container {
overflow: hidden;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}   

#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 10000;
  position: relative;
  }


#information {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.2;
  top: 150px;
  color: #FFF;
}

#information h3 {
 margin: 3px 3px; 
 text-align: center;
}

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var topInitial = "0";
      var topAfter = "150px";

      $(function() {

      /*
      $("#box").mouseover(function(){
      $("#information").css("top",topInitial); }); 


      $("#box").mouseout(function() {
      $("#information").css("top",topAfter); });      
      });
      */

      $("#box").mouseover(function() {  
      $("#information").animate({
      top: 0 }, "slow"); });

      $("#box").mouseout(function() {
      $("#information").animate({
      top: 150 }, "slow"); });

      //New Code
      $("#container").click(function() {
  $("#container").animate({
  margin-left: 30}, "slow"); });

     });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="container">
  <div id="box">
  <div id="information">
  <h3> Criminal Penguins Having a Ball </h3>
  <p> You have never seen something like this before!</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

My problem is, the mouseover event is happening many times. Can someone tell me how to rectify this issue? Another important query, since I've only begun to code I'm sure I'll hit some roadblocks in the future as well. Should I then create a new thread with the modified code or will editing this thread work? Please help! :)

Update: I've just added some new code in my Javascript. I want to move the element to the right by 30px. Is this the way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead of `mouseover`. Mouse enter will be called once it enters the element.

Change your function as below,

```
   $("#box").mouseenter(function() {  
      $("#information").animate({
        top: 0 }, "slow"); 
   });
```

Also you can change your script like below,

```
  $("#box").mouseenter(function() {  
     $("#information").animate({
     top: 0 }, "slow"); 
  }).mouseleave(function() {
     $("#information").animate({
     top: 150 }, "slow"); 
  });
```

You can read about all jQuery mouse events [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/)

Comment: Thanks SKS, just what I wanted. Any idea about the second query?

Comment: You should post a new question rather than editing the original post. Also try to search for what you want before you post, because it might have been answered already. You can always link to this post if you think that would make more sense than repeating the same.

Comment: Err.. I've just updated my query to include one more issue. If you could check it out, SKS.

Comment: Use marginLeft instead of margin-left.